# Password protection for NetCat shell?

Tags: backdoor, network-access-control, netcat

As a pentester, I often use NetCat, and its encrypted counterpart CryptCat. However, even CryptCat only encrypts the traffic.

I'm looking for a way to keep unauthorized users from gaining access to the backdoors I have created. I guess I could whitelist the static IP of my computer, and block all other LAN connections to prevent others from connecting, but by no means is that an ideal solution. I feel like there should be some NetCat-like derivative that supports both encryption and password protection out of the box.

How can I prevent unauthorized access to a NetCat backdoor?

Comment: TLS or SSH tunnel?

Comment: Make reverse connections instead of listening on a port?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Do you know of a way to SSH into a windows machine without using third-party software?

Comment: @VerbalKint `nc` isn't third party?

Comment: What a weird way to poorly reimplement ssh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not aware of an existing solution. Assuming you are using something like `nc -l -p 4444 -e /bin/sh`, you could write a script that would be called instead of sh and acts as a password protecting wrapper for sh.

Comment: Hm, interesting approach certainly. I'm remoting into a windows command shell from Linux, but the same concept could work. I guess that's probably the best I can do within the confines of NetCat

Answer (score 0):

There's [a guide on the metasploit git](https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/wiki/Meterpreter-Paranoid-Mode) on how to generate a "paranoid Meterpreter payload and listener", which is basically a SSL/TLS certificate protected reverse shell.

I'm very new to metasploit, so I'm not sure if this would work for a bind shell, but I'm posting it in case it helps anybody else.